# How to read a poscar file which is a surface and add adsorbates using ASE

Tags: surfaces, atomic-simulation-environment, adsorption

I have a POSCAR file containing Co, Cr, Fe, Ni elements. It is a slab of 6 layers. The first 3 layers are mobile whiles the last three layers are fixed. I would like to add adsorbates at the FCC hollow sites. From my count, I would need 15 oxygen atoms at the different hollow sites. I don't want to include hcp hollow sites. How do I read the poscar file into ASE to maintain the surface and vacuum and only add the adsorbate? I have attached the poscar file.

```
CoCrFeNi
   1.00000000000000     
     9.9633502299999996    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
    -4.9733836199999999    8.6618479100000005    0.0000000000000000
     0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   40.4368920000000003
   Co   Cr   Fe   Ni
    24    24    24    24
Selective dynamics
Direct
  0.5612360243849388  0.9099052137287840  0.6250221820654160   T   T   T
  0.2356071120850486  0.2518526753215678  0.5772064214469697   T   T   T
  0.2348146468815286  0.7507696751875000  0.5764034425400485   T   T   T
  0.4860087088559321  0.5025000099364838  0.5766204786838768   T   T   T
  0.4832051517095323  0.9985833850246899  0.5770138532476135   T   T   T
  0.4854835901844644  0.7512215609776637  0.5763813008840900   T   T   T
  0.2355456895711744  0.9978683794875377  0.5777498674746212   T   T   T
  0.9867436499750243  0.5059613373927444  0.5769244369303035   T   T   T
  0.9038462779907266  0.5846022973376531  0.5260416228921621   T   T   T
  0.5716581887774268  0.9201204041921329  0.4758342950788617   F   F   F
  0.5741257856744610  0.4187527924396477  0.4757376011984320   F   F   F
  0.8221917385325952  0.1698063756466937  0.4754235315612263   F   F   F
  0.8188510224305006  0.6661687044098628  0.4754012746578056   F   F   F
  0.8238998402551019  0.4200678697901523  0.4748374331044047   F   F   F
  0.5727204154956951  0.6689043793196774  0.4747973706782389   F   F   F
  0.3230897361863398  0.1691307692332842  0.4746252506250954   F   F   F
  0.2362167951761762  0.2470966960213019  0.4240635012206155   F   F   F
  0.9075250613866288  0.5865598256619577  0.3747389883475734   F   F   F
  0.9099926467579991  0.0851921908197042  0.3746422944671437   F   F   F
  0.1580586012731757  0.8362458075069128  0.3743282248299380   F   F   F
  0.1547179181243052  0.3326081258796876  0.3743059679265173   F   F   F
  0.1597667301860781  0.0865072797151001  0.3737421263731164   F   F   F
  0.9085872881049042  0.3353438007895022  0.3737020639469506   F   F   F
  0.6589565758423106  0.8355702010934962  0.3735299438938071   F   F   F
  0.8058501908443986  0.1604085948745253  0.6276226743697434   T   T   T
  0.0711651015373968  0.1740917158429164  0.6283794021117671   T   T   T
  0.5585537014512123  0.1589400490967113  0.6274647415475056   T   T   T
  0.8408195288613217  0.4120066169412361  0.6276226664037110   T   T   T
  0.8218106695859454  0.6771528044496808  0.6304296582071180   T   T   T
  0.0835097517099495  0.4214918947625969  0.6290440423670955   T   T   T
  0.2375735696515378  0.5010054481380813  0.5770179622858687   T   T   T
  0.7358517176793846  0.5001337489919461  0.5753017076229778   T   T   T
  0.1526774569984566  0.8311508061347753  0.5260862055103875   T   T   T
  0.4012780008378368  0.8374455841948802  0.5256159156652330   T   T   T
  0.9015458337759297  0.8318449292366887  0.5267321752290328   T   T   T
  0.1650345374797721  0.0820828245082830  0.5266625182108280   T   T   T
  0.1530715796942058  0.3284398123835934  0.5256954404458725   T   T   T
  0.4037759574840217  0.0881761973292648  0.5266741240986712   T   T   T
  0.5719291831091056  0.1671338512338281  0.4751517500405313   F   F   F
  0.0726206267831913  0.1688011628918105  0.4750530777686848   F   F   F
  0.4902349088201277  0.5006121147652394  0.4250452779605283   F   F   F
  0.7387644569889744  0.5022689205818693  0.4249752923642092   F   F   F
  0.2384726428149762  0.4987219869114483  0.4248748889998737   F   F   F
  0.4894111111794288  0.7512741008171346  0.4248244400187815   F   F   F
  0.4908000549497729  0.0025951829486672  0.4244191170775409   F   F   F
  0.7393419908448990  0.7494893777233287  0.4241708289549067   F   F   F
  0.9077960227650834  0.8335732830940472  0.3740564433092430   F   F   F
  0.4084875035752731  0.8352405947520296  0.3739577710373965   F   F   F
  0.0714088580284006  0.9241042308280607  0.6266688247630529   T   T   T
  0.0712936348301734  0.6734806713146717  0.6264448440732556   T   T   T
  0.5661143764171257  0.6694797179385326  0.6276482980086926   T   T   T
  0.5826565215444279  0.4197094481854535  0.6248967461469209   T   T   T
  0.9863437963371268  0.0049281853325266  0.5778527630146324   T   T   T
  0.7299839656132034  0.7483226508951495  0.5771810032009886   T   T   T
  0.9822818352016206  0.7481102940128979  0.5771714159167410   T   T   T
  0.4836853691620328  0.2504096534801669  0.5765478188719351   T   T   T
  0.4023001272576696  0.5849271527966273  0.5256599968038801   T   T   T
  0.4052342653716023  0.3382546586388231  0.5252451653467152   T   T   T
  0.9035134348127880  0.3352264766627390  0.5263625912611249   T   T   T
  0.9027949755174263  0.0791523962176613  0.5260593633310788   T   T   T
  0.3232407866261937  0.6702789128053368  0.4755137956695563   F   F   F
  0.0665275574938846  0.4173909583226560  0.4755078604953127   F   F   F
  0.3245013047405436  0.4173221508342095  0.4749788880906110   F   F   F
  0.8209027016053341  0.9159207229719186  0.4747226864023091   F   F   F
  0.7400046718620530  0.2526014105458927  0.4255408650100989   F   F   F
  0.7373990205197032  0.9972170014700694  0.4251333163785205   F   F   F
  0.2401126400303042  0.0008789443175559  0.4246560294495438   F   F   F
  0.2420278484524303  0.7522265534676222  0.4244614051940516   F   F   F
  0.6591076592354028  0.3367183342751616  0.3744184889382680   F   F   F
  0.4023944301030866  0.0838303797924809  0.3744125537640244   F   F   F
  0.6603682004010807  0.0837616184835568  0.3738835813593226   F   F   F
  0.1567695396708118  0.5823600289929374  0.3736276269699488   F   F   F
  0.8139283773437237  0.9179970463961956  0.6264927519830703   T   T   T
  0.3316971715924403  0.4206428344420928  0.6270248681347872   T   T   T
  0.3156932809260076  0.9156706536874418  0.6266447810285281   T   T   T
  0.3193842754680041  0.6705125009466922  0.6268440812499967   T   T   T
  0.3204197280025719  0.1699424665767754  0.6272751272551228   T   T   T
  0.7346622986391906  0.2521520822199035  0.5767044378177472   T   T   T
  0.7337753457319838 -0.0000484138730764  0.5764088122275434   T   T   T
  0.9859905944062034  0.2532340884891014  0.5767699223686655   T   T   T
  0.1520510767833566  0.5824068293232663  0.5262650644687904   T   T   T
  0.6539763846918202  0.0840366980125778  0.5258262367600025   T   T   T
  0.6540657686858518  0.5846162808349679  0.5256774417697333   T   T   T
  0.6542669891634135  0.3357645143656891  0.5254505398702217   T   T   T
  0.6510606874754463  0.8330745611877558  0.5256560801844358   T   T   T
  0.0765196813155740  0.9206583956286494  0.4765519565648120   F   F   F
  0.0658167894639234  0.6668927993218503  0.4761879325443701   F   F   F
  0.3165218299266357  0.9183686994568774  0.4733637787988272   F   F   F
  0.4845041515414152  0.2488359322854947  0.4251788193810739   F   F   F
  0.9902804335043385  0.7510055668940936  0.4248024304142888   F   F   F
  0.9888284822195317  0.2504328201717385  0.4244866296845942   F   F   F
  0.9943961297937989  0.9996431581306737  0.4242620822589416   F   F   F
  0.9866011241072812  0.4984118914182147  0.4231390978317506   F   F   F
  0.4123865539247760  0.5870978170984742  0.3754566498335237   F   F   F
  0.4016836620731254  0.3333322207916751  0.3750926258130818   F   F   F
  0.6523887025358377  0.5848081209267022  0.3722684720675389   F   F   F
```

Comment: I can definitely help you but I don't see the "attached poscar file".

Comment: @ShaunHan Please I can't find the attach button. Can you just create any surface and save it as poscar file then use it to demonstrate it to me?

Comment: You don't need to attach the file. You can simply put the text in your poscar file in the question.

Comment: @ShaunHan I've added the poscar to the original post. Thanks

Comment: Please use a `code` block.

Comment: If your final goal is to create POSCAR only. I will suggest you to visualise current POSCAR in ovito or Vesta and edit atoms manually.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought you have a 6-layer surface slab with Co, Cr, Fe, Ni metals, but the POSCAR you provided shows you have a 3-layer Cr$_2$O$_3$(0001) surface slab. Note that the adsorption site identification on metal oxide surfaces is much more complicated than on metal surfaces.

Comment: @ShaunHan Ya sorry, I copied the wrong POSCAR file. I have updated it. Thanks

Comment: @Pranavkumar My motive is to be able to supply ASE with a POSCAR file and identify the adsorption sites on the surface. Then add adsorbates to these adsorption sites and save the new file as POSCAR again. Having a code determine the adsorption sites would be more correct than doing it manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember running into exactly the same issue like you when I just started my PhD. In ASE, there is this [`ase.build.add_adsorbate()`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/build/surface.html#ase.build.add_adsorbate) function that allows placing a single adsorbate on a surface site. However, this function has the following limitations:

- the clean surface slab must be generated by `ase.build`;
- only allow one pre-defined position for each type of site;
- for alloy systems it does not differentiate two sites of the same type (e.g. bridge) but different elemental compositions (e.g. AA, BB and AB);
- limited number of supported surfaces;
- nanoparticles/clusters are not supported.

I then looked into other codes with similar functions, e.g. [Pymatgen](https://pymatgen.org/), [CatKit](https://catkit.readthedocs.io/), etc, but to the best of my knowledge, they all require a pre-defined bulk/surface structure to identify adsorption sites. So I decided to develop a code by myself, namely [ACAT](https://asm-dtu.gitlab.io/acat/).

ACAT overcomes all aforementioned limitations, providing a general way of identifying adsorption sites on an *arbitrary* surface structure (i.e. any `ase.Atoms` object) that can represent a wide variety of surfaces and nanoparticles. In detail, ACAT implements the adsorption site identification for 20 common low-index surfaces (including fcc, bcc and hcp crystal structures) in `acat.adsorption_sites.SlabAdsorptionSites` and for 3 common nanoparticle motifs (fcc, icosahedron, and decahedron) in `acat.adsorption_sites.ClusterAdsorptionSites`.

Let's come back to your question. You can first read the POSCAR using ASE:

```
from ase.io import read
from ase.visualize import view

atoms = read('POSCAR')
view(atoms)
```

And your clean alloy fcc(111) surface looks like this

[image]

You can then use ACAT to identify all high-symmetry adsorption sites on the fcc(111) surface, i.e. ontop, bridge, fcc and hcp sites.

```
from acat.adsorption_sites import SlabAdsorptionSites

sas = SlabAdsorptionSites(atoms, surface='fcc111')
sites = sas.get_sites()
```

This `sites` object is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary stores the information of one site. If you print out one dictionary, you will see something like this:

```
print(sites[0])
# {'site': 'ontop', 'surface': 'fcc111', 'morphology': 'terrace', 'position': array([ 1.06648339,  7.88146057, 25.27395447]), 'normal': array([-0.00176619, -0.00244269,  0.99999546]), 'indices': (0,), 'composition': None, 'subsurf_index': None, 'subsurf_element': None, 'label': None}
```

where the 'site', 'surface', 'morphology', 'position', 'normal', 'indices' and 'composition' keys contain information of the type, the locating surface, the local geometric environment, the Cartesian coordinate, the normal vector, the atomic indices and the elemental composition of the site, respectively.

Now that we want to add adsorbates to specific sites, e.g. adding O to all fcc sites as you requested, we can just use a for loop with the `acat.build.add_adsorbate_to_site` function (you can change the `height` parameter to adjust the bond distance between the adsorbates and the surface):

```
from acat.build import add_adsorbate_to_site

for st in sites:
    if st['site'] == 'fcc':
        add_adsorbate_to_site(atoms, adsorbate='O', site=st, height=1.)
view(atoms)
```

Just like that, you get the structure you want

[image]

The code can be installed simply by `pip install acat`. For more usage of the ACAT package, I strongly recommend this [Jupyter notebook tutorial](https://gitlab.com/asm-dtu/acat/-/blob/master/notebooks/acat_tutorial.ipynb). Remember to cite if you find the code useful for your research :)

Comment: I never knew you developed that code. I have been trying to wrap my head around it and hear you are live in colored. Thank you very much for your answer. I really appreciate your effort. Installed acat four days ago but couldn't create what you have done. Thanks once again.

Comment: This is just a follow up question. Wanted to find out if your code can calculate the surface area of the slab. I don't know if taking the cross product of the lattice vectors a and b and finding the magnitiude of the resulting vector is correct. Any comment on that would be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @NanaKofiBoakye Yes that's correct. Even for stepped surfaces, you can calculate surface area by the cross product. It's called the *cross-sectional surface area*. See [this post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/8680/how-to-calculate-the-surface-area-of-a-stepped-surface-slab-in-a-unit-cell)

Comment: Thank you once again. You've been helpful to me. Any social handle to follow you would be appreciated.